# Wired internet not working

Tags: networking, wired

I have just installed Lubuntu 14.04 yesterday. After installation the Internet was working pretty well. I downloaded a couple of programs from  software center.

But today when I tried to open my browser, it does not work. The connection button on my panel keeps on blinking and on console it says 'access concentrator of your provider did not respond'.

I use a wired connection. Please help me.  I don't have much networking knowledge.

Comment: Could you please include the output for next commands, run in terminal: `sudo lshw -C network` 

`ifconfig -a`

`route -n`

`ping -c4 www.google.com`

Comment: Are you sure you have internet access? It sounds like it might be a problem with your internet service provider.

Comment: @ rusian. thanks for reply. i typed the command but it doesnot say anything important. may be i typed it wrong or something: sudo lshw -c networkifconfig -a route -nping -c 4 www.google.com

Comment: i inserted the cable in my other laptop with window 7 where internet opened and then again into my desktop. but to my suprise it worked. i dont know what happened but it works just fine now.  thanks for your support. i think there is problem with lubuntu networking.

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear user296596,

First! *Relax* and listen to the **comments** of your answer. Your Laptop/PC/Whatever still works and welcome abroad to Ubuntu.

Nothing bad happened.

Welcome.